# Save a GDAL dataset to Django file field

Tags: python, gdal, django

I am processing a raster image inside my Django app. From a GeoTIFF file I am converting it to a COG. I am using gdal.Translate for the operation. I want to save the processed image without saving it locally. I want to use the GDAL dataset to read its bytes and be saved in a Django model's file field.

But suppose in this example, I am opening a dataset using gdal.Open. How can I save that to FileField?

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db.models.fields.files import FileField
import osgeo
from osgeo import gdal

dataset = gdal.Open('/path/to/dataset.tif')
data_bytes = dataset.ReadAsArray().tobytes()

file_field = FileField()
file_field.save('dataset.tif', content_file, save=False)

model_instance = MyModel(file_field=file_field)
model_instance.save()
```

I am using GDAL 3.2.2.1 due to some constraints. Does function ReadAsArray not available in the version?

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo._gdal_array'

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file to the expected destination with GDAL and just update the model.

With the `storage` attribute of the `FileField` you can get the expected path.

```py
output_raster_name = "my_raster.tif"

# If you don't have an instance at this point just create a fake one
# my_model = MyModel()
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_pk)

# This returns an absolute path taking into accound settings.MEDIA_ROOT
# and upload_to
output_raster = my_model.file_field.storage.path(name=output_raster_name)


dataset = gdal.Open("/path/to/dataset.tif")
warp = gdal.Warp(output_raster, dataset, dstSRS="EPSG:4326")
warp = None # Closes the files
```

If you are not using `FileSysteStorage` probably you can use more or less the same trick using [GDAL Virtual File Systems](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3-aws-s3-files), but i don't have experience doing it.

Also I think that [gdal_array](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal_array.html#module-osgeo.gdal_array) module should be present in your GDAL version so this shoud work:

```
from osgeo import gdal_array

# dataset_numpyarray = gdal_array.LoadFile("/path/to/dataset.tif")
# or

dataset = gdal.Open("/path/to/dataset.tif")
data_bytes = gdal_array.DatasetReadAsArray(dataset).tobytes()
```

Comment: This is tricky. What if I am using a cloud storage such as S3 or Google Cloud?

Comment: Hi! I was able to write the file. However, the model object does not reference the `file_field` to that saved file/location. Am I missing something? Of course I saved i.e. `my_model.save()`